# When is "PLMN not allowed" error code seen in LTE?

Tags: wireless

When is "PLMN not allowed" error code seen in LTE? I know its seen when the device tries a location registration in a PLMN in which its barred. But how can it even send the attach request to it in the first place?

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

The Attach-Request PDU is encapsulated in the rrcConnectionSetupComplete message. Also in the rrcConnectionSetupComplete message is a field called selectedPLMN-Identity, whose value refers to a PLMN chosen from the plmn-IdentityList from SIB1. The Attach-Request PDU contains information from which to derive the PLMN of the SIM the mobile is using. So the mobile is telling the base station the PLMN it wants to use, and the PLMN of its SIM. Based on those two pieces of information, higher layer entities can determine whether to reject w/ the "PLMN not allowed" message.

To answer how a mobile can send the attach request, the answer to that is simply how the attach procedure works. There is no unique identifying information transmitted by the mobile user until the RRCConnectionSetupComplete message.